# Miranda's book proposition 1.6 pag. 60

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Riemann surfaces. Suppose that $U \subset X$ and $V \subset Y$ are nonempty open sets, and there is given an isomorphism $\phi: U \mapsto V$ between them. Then there is a unique complex structure on the identification space $Z = X \sqcup Y / \phi$ such that the natural inclusions of $X$ and $Y$ into $Z$ are holomorphic. In particular, if $Z$ is Hausdorff, it is a Riemann surface.
How can I proof the compatibility between the charts $(\psi \circ j_X)$ and $(\phi \circ j_Y)?$ In which sense he says that “If we desire the natural inclusions of $X$ and $Y$ into $Z$ to be holomorphic, these charts are forced on us”?

Comment: I see that you've posted several questions about Riemann surfaces in the past couple of hours. In the future you may want to post one or two at a time because if not, it seems like you haven't attempted to answer them (I'm not saying you haven't).

Comment: Let $j_X: X \mapsto Z$ and $j_Y: Y \mapsto Z$ be the natural inclusions. For every chart $\psi: U_\alpha \mapsto \psi(U_\alpha)$ on $X$, take the open set $j_X(U_\alpha) \subset Z$ by using $\psi \circ j_x^{-1}$. I have to proof that these charts are compatible. Clearly $\psi j_X^{-1} j_X \psi^{-1}$ is holomorphic; similarly, for every chart $\phi: V_\alpha \mapsto \phi(V_\alpha)$ on $Y$, $\phi j_Y^{-1} j_Y \phi^{-1}$. I want to show that $\psi j_X^{-1}j_Y \phi^{-1}$ is holomorphic.

Comment: In which sense he says that “If we desire the natural inclusions of X  and Y  into Z  to be holomorphic, these charts are forced on us”? I can't understand  the English sense of this sentence, hence I can translate it correctly.

Comment: I answered your first question below. As far as the English translation, first we see that the charts he chooses are homeomorphisms. Now, if we want the inclusions to be holomorphic, these charts are essentially the inclusions written in local coordinates, and so they must be holomorphic. Therefore the charts chosen are actually holomorphic charts. So basically, if you want the inclusions to be holomorphic, you're going to have to have these charts in your atlas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you used $\phi$ for two different things, so let me change the notation. Let $p\in U$, and let $\eta$ be a coordinate chart at $p$ and let $\psi$ be a coordinate chart at $\phi(p)$ (defined on certain open sets, etc...). We can then use these as coordinate charts on $Z$; let's call them $\hat\eta$ and $\hat\psi$. Then $\hat\psi\circ\hat\eta^{-1}$ does the following (on the intersection of the domains, etc...):
$$z\mapsto\eta^{-1}(z)=\phi(\eta^{-1}(z))\mapsto\psi(\phi(\eta^{-1}(z)))=(\psi\circ\phi\circ\eta^{-1})(z).$$
This is just the local equation for $\phi$, and by definition it is holomorphic. Therefore the change of coordinates is also holomorphic.